# 0x80004005 when performing administrative tasks

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-11, uac

We have an AD network, and a group of users has higher privileges than the standard, configured via GPO in *Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Restricted Groups*. One of those users have problems on their computer: when they attempt to perform actions which requires higher privileges, the UAC prompt appears, they enter their password, but action fails for the generic error above.

I.e. I was trying to run troubleshooting resolution on the printer, and it fails with 0x80004005. While using a Domain Admin it works.

This apparently happens on this computer only, I haven't tried logging with the same user on another computer, nor logging with a different user on this PC. Other users on other computer aren't reporting permission issues.

The computer has no domain-related issues: `gpupdate` runs without errors, connection test to the DC is successful.

Comment: Error code 0x80004005 is likely in this case related to permissions or profile corruption. Trying another profile would be useful. You could also try generic tests such as by [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I did ran Dism and sfc, didn't reboot yet as they were using it. If it's related to permissions, why is it working for other computers in the domain? Indeed could be profile-related